# Why python integer caches range [-5, 256] don't work in similar way on all platform?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, google-colaboratory, python-idle

## For example:

### In `pycharm`:

```
a = 256
b = 256
print(a is b)
>>>True  # This is fine.
```

#### But!

```
a = 257
b = 257
print(a is b)
>>>True  # This should be False.
```

### In `Colaboratory/IDLE/etc.`:

```
a = 256
b = 256
print(a is b)
>>>True  # This is fine.


a = 257
b = 257
print(a is b)
>>>False  # This is fine.
```

According to theory:

An integer is referenced in that range, Python will use the cached version of that object. So memory address will be the same.

Expect pycharm this works everywhere.

### Can anyone tell me what's the problem.

Comment: CPython doesn't cache 257 *on any platform*. You are seeing the effects of constant, immutable literals being cached, when that happens is not straightforward, necessarily, usually, constant literals are cached if they are part of the same "block", so how exactly your code is being compiled matters. This happens with string literals as well

Comment: Also note, there are corner cases in CPython where the integer cache is bypassed, so this is something that should **never** be relied on

Comment: TL;DR: This is an implementation detail which depends not only on several factors within one platform, but can vary widely between different platforms. You should never expect `<int> is <int>` to deliver any particular result in the first place, so how or why exactly it works is really a moot point.

Comment: This is weird... IDLE or Pycharm are only human interfaces over true Python interpretors. I cannot imagine why using one or the other could change anything *by the simple interface*. What can change is that they could use different Python versions or load different modules.

Comment: To simplify; it happens because in your first example the whole block is compiled before being run - which allows the compiler to optimize it before the code runs, while in the second case each statement is being compiled and run by itself - meaning that only the small integer cache comes into effect. Do not rely on this in any way. If you save your statements to a file and run that, it'll show the same result as PyCharm.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I could see that the way a REPL is implemented could affect this. So in the REPL, each input is compiled and evaluated as a single block. Not so for a module

Comment: So, for example, even in a REPL, `a = 1000; b = 1000; print(a is b)` will print `True`

Comment: And note, there is also constant folding, so `500 + 500 is 1000` will print `True`... in any case, what @deceze says is true... these are all implementation details that shouldn't be relied on. *It's not theory*, it's quirks of the implementation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: That, I can understand! I was misleaded because I use IDLE and Pycharm exactly the same way with some code in an edit window and some code in the *console* window. Anyway, thanks for the head up...

Comment: @SergeBallesta yeah, it's not clear to me how exactly the OP is running the code to begin with.

Comment: (As an aside, I really do wonder why these questions about integers and `is` crop up every now and then – do people really think they need to know this behavior and/or use `is` that much?)

Comment: @AKX I think it's one of the first peeks behind the curtain that someone learning python stumbles upon, and it just piques curiosity. Definitely, probably the first time I looked at CPython source code was at the integer implementation!

Comment: the `id` function can be useful to see what's going on.  try running `(id(257), id(257))` at the REPL a couple of times

Comment: I ran the 3 line program from an IDLE editor in 3.7 and 3.9 and it prints True.  What version and OS and did you actually run from editor or did you edit Shell log to make it look like editor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To simplify what has been mentioned in the comments above and further illustrate it:

It happens because in your first example the whole block is compiled before being run - which allows the compiler to optimize it before the code itself is invoked, while in the second case each statement is being compiled and run by itself (without knowing anything about the previous statements).

In the latter case only the small integer cache comes into effect, since the compiler doesn't know anything about the previous statements.

Do not rely on this in any way. If you save your statements to a file and run that, it'll show the same result as PyCharm:

```
~ cat test.py
a = 257
b = 257
print(a is b)
~ python3 test.py
True
~ python test.py
True
```

You can also replicate this behaviour in the REPL by giving it a single block to compile:

```
>>> def test():
...   a = 257
...   b = 257
...   print(a is b)
...
>>> test()
True
```